# lambda expression error in python

Tags: python, list, lambda, nltk

I tried to developed a lambda expression classification. Following is my code so far,

```
import nltk
list2=nltk.word_tokenize("I win it")
list1 = ['gain', 'archive', 'win', 'success']

set1 = set(list1)
result = []
for item, nextitem in zip(list2, list2[1:]):
if item in set1:
    result.append(nextitem)
print result

new_result =nltk.pos_tag(result)
words, tags = zip(*new_result)

def classify(s, rls):
  for (f, emotion) in rls:
  if f(s):
     return emotion
 return "neutral"

rules = [(lambda x: x[result != []] & [['PRP' in(tags)]], "happy"),
     (lambda x: x[result != []] & [['PRP' not in(tags)]], "neutral"),]

 print classify("I successfully done my exam", rules)
```

But it makes following error.

```
rules = [(lambda x: x[result != []] & [['PRP' in(tags)]], "happy"),
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'list'
```

How can I fix this error. Please help me !

Comment: `&` is the bitwise operator, not the logical `and`

Comment: Which operator should I use instead of &?

Comment: `and` the literal word `and`: `rules = [(lambda x: x[result != []] and [['PRP' in(tags)]], "happy"),`

Comment: Use `and`; the basic logical operators are built-in functions.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `some_expression and [['PRP' in(tags)]]` will have the same boolean outcome as if you had just written `some_expression` by itself. `[[False]]` is just as truthy as `[[True]]`.

Comment: What are the semantics of the lambda function you're trying to write?  Your syntax has several problems.  I think you need to read the documentation on lambda syntax, boolean expressions, ternary operator, and ... well, pretty much every small expression type you've tried to use here.

Comment: Yes the lamda function result doesn't work as I expected. But it does not show any syntax error. Can you tell me what would be the wrong with it.

Comment: `x in(list)` isn't a valid syntax in python. `x in list` would be valid.

Comment: Your code is all over the place, you need to debug it and fix it yourself. Try going through the statements of `classify()` by hand: E.g., debug `rules[0][0]("I successfully done my exam")`.